# htaccess external domain to new domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have asked my domain host provider to point a website to my public_html folder. but now I have been told the if I need this other domain to redirect to a particular url on my primary domain website, I would need to do it in the htaccess file. At the moment I have researched and this is what my htaccess looks like without any luck!

```
# Switch rewrite engine off in case this was installed under HostPay.
RewriteEngine Off

SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 5

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherdomain.org.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.primarydomain.org/blog/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

The above does not redirect my otherdomain.org.uk to the blog page on my primarydomain.org/blog. Please note that my primarydomain.org/blog is a wordpress website page.

Comment: You need redirection rule on the `otherdomain.org.uk` server's `DocumentRoot` folder.

Comment: The otherdomain.org.uk point to the same public_html folder where the primarydomain.org's htaccess file exists. At the moment the otherdomain.org.uk redirects to primarydomain.org but not primarydomain.org/blog/

Comment: Please not that this is a wordpress page so the url doesnt not actually reflect on a document folder

Answer (score 1):

Keep redirect rules before your WP rules.

Have your rules like this:

```
# Switch rewrite engine off in case this was installed under HostPay.
RewriteEngine Off

SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 5

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^otherdomain.org.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.primarydomain.org/blog/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I just tried that with no luck. the otherdomain.org.uk is still redirecting to the primarydomain.org but not to the blog page

Comment: Did you test it in a new browser? Also open this UR in Firebug and see under Net tab how many redirects are you getting?

Comment: I am not familiar with Firebug. I tried in another browser and still doesn't do what the htaccess is meant to do

Comment: I installed firebug and I am looking at the console but I cannot identify any redirects.

Comment: If not in Firebug then do same in Chrome developer tool and do check in Network tab what redirects are shown.

Comment: Yes it redirects to primarydomain.org but it is not going to primarydomain.org/blog/ . it is only redirecting to primarydomain.org at the moment because it the otherdomain.org is pointing to the public_html folder. the web host provider told me to do the work in the htaccess and that would get it redirecting to the blog link

Comment: What is the URL you enter in your browser before redirect?

Comment: I enter otherdomain.org.uk and it goes to primarydomain.org but I want it to go to primarydomain.org/blog/

Comment: When you enter `primarydomain.org/blog/` does it stay at that URL?

Comment: the primarydomain.org/blog works because that is the main website. but if I type otherdomain.org.uk/blog it does not redirect to primarydomain.org/blog. All I want to do is get otherdomain.org.uk to redirect to primarydomain.org/blog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61584/discussion-between-anubhava-and-user3214892).